# Old mainboard can't boot from USB, ISO file is 6 GB, How can I format in this situation?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, dvd, iso-image

It's an old mainboard and it can't boot from USB, because boot from HDD includes the  usb and hdd option.

So, if I choose usb, HDD won't work. I have to format this computer with just floppy disk or cd/dvd. I've got an ISO that has a size of 6 GB (Windows 7 ISO). But DVD is just 4.7 GB. I got 2 empty DVD so how can I burn this large iso to 2 DVD. And will it work?

Basically I tried Winrar > Adding Archive technique but I couldn't.

I split it 3 gb but first rar show it's 5 gb, second is 1 gb. I don't know why it happened. I'm also not sure if this is a viable solution.

Comment: Use a standard Windows 7 image (should be less than 6 GB); use LiveCD to copy the image to a bootable partition and install from the HDD; use a dual layer DVD which should have sufficient space. Using 2 separate DVDs won't work (easily). What do you mean by "Winrar>Adding Archive technique"?

Comment: This is probably not an official Windows 7 installation ISO. Otherwise it should have been much smaller!

Comment: "when the installation is working from USB, HDD won't work so there is not a place to install." - This sounds like a UEFI/MBR conflict.  If you boot the installation environment in Compatability Mode (CM/Legacy) it means you cannot install to NVMe based disks or any GPT disk (the device will not show up).  Likewise if you have CM disable, only GPT disks will show up, which is what you actually want.  **It is not possible to span a Windows 7 installatin disk across multiple optical drives.**

Answer (score 2):

> It's an old mainboard and it can't boot from USB, because boot from HDD include the usb and hdd option. So, if I choose usb, HDD isn't work

Changing the boot mode really shouldn't prevent the HDD from working *at all*.  Most likely it just means the HDD won't be used for booting, but it'll still work in the actual OS. (Most old motherboards which can't boot from USB don't offer the option at all...)

If that's the case, there is no problem – set it to boot from USB first; start the installation; before letting the installer reboot, set it to boot from HDD again.

> I've got an ISO that 6 GB (Windows 7 ISO)

Official Windows 7 ISOs from MSDN or VLSC aren't that large – they're usually 2.9 to 3.5 GB.

Did you make a combined 32/64-bit variant, or did you download something weird from somewhere weird? Consider downloading an official unmodified ISO image instead; there are websites archiving those.

> DVD is just 4.7 GB.

You can use a dual-layer disc (DVD+R DL), which is 8.5 GB.

> I got 2 empty DVD so how can i burn this large iso to 2 DVD.

You cannot do it without modifications.

It's possible to split the largest file (Windows .wim image) into multiple pieces, and Microsoft actually has [some kind of instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/split-a-windows-image--wim--file-to-span-across-multiple-dvds) for doing so.

However, because you don't have any alternative installer to boot from, you'd need to carefully rebuild the "first" image (e.g. using ImgBurn), taking care to preserve the bootloader image (eltorito) and everything else – just replacing the .wim with a split .swm part.

> Basicly I tried Winrar>Adding Archive technique but I couldn't. I split it 3 gb but first rar show it's 5 gb, second is 1 gb. I don't know why it happened. I'm also not sure if this is work.

It won't. The PC firmware won't be able to boot from a RAR archive, and Windows Setup won't be able to find its own files inside a RAR archive either.

Comment: First of all, when the installation is working from USB, HDD won't work so there is not a place to install. This option don't work on my computer. 

Second, I couldn't download the original MSDN version because it needs product key for even just downloading. I find 2 place for kind of safety download, windowsiso.net and Heidoc. Windowsiso.net had dead links. Heidoc couldn't download the last version too but there was a version that updated last summer in Heidoc and I did download from there. I think theese are not that "somewhere weird" And "No.", I only downloaded 64 bit.

Comment: I'm not a fool who doesn't know the pc won't be able to setup from a RAR archive in the boot. I thought if I can split the ISO, this might makes me a fool :d. If you know how can I download the original ISO without product key, let me know. Otherwise, I will buy a dual-layer disk tonight. I guess this is the only choice right now.

Comment: @GereksizMail - You can download a [Windows 7 ISO](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft/1046062#1046062), directly from Microsoft, you don't need a key to acomplish that. There are also third-party applications like Windows ISO Downloader, they download the ISO, directly from Microsoft.  **An official Windows 7 ISO should be fit on a traditional 4.7 GB optical disk.**

Comment: The only working solution is Heidoc in the page. As I mention that, I already used Heidoc. It is downloading almost 6 GB ISO.

Comment: @GereksizMail, I don't know what you are downloading, but the standard distribution **en_windows_7_professional_x64_dvd.iso** is just 3.09 Gbytes. You can download all "updates" later.